# Javascript to change and save background onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the background of the page using divs with onlick function but it is not changing anything, neither saving to localStorage. Here is what I have until now

HTML

```
<div class="colors" onclick="setBackground('#ECF3F9')">Elegant</div>

<div class="colors" onclick="setBackground('#F1F9EC')">Modern</div>

<div class="colors" onclick="setBackground('#F2EBDD')">Classic</div>

<div class="colors" onclick="setBackground('#121212')">Dark</div>
```

The CSS

```
.colors {display:inline-block;width:50px;height:30px;border:1px solid black;margin:10px;}
```

and the simple javascript

```
function setBackground(color) 
{
localStorage.setItem("name", color);

}
if(localStorage.name)   //Accessing name variable of localStorage.
{
document.body.style.background = localStorage.name;
}
```

I also create a Codepen to see it in action
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/BaGLeBj

Any idea why it is not saving the changes onclick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to actually change the background color of the page.

The following code won't work in Stack Overflow because it's sandboxed, but it will work outside of SO.

```js
// Don't use inline event attributes like onXyz. 
// Separate your JavaScript from your HTML and set up events
// the modern way.
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  setBackground(event, event.target.classList[0]);
});

if(localStorage.name) {
  // Accessing name variable of localStorage
  document.body.classList.add(localStorage.name);
}

function setBackground(event, color) {
  if(event.target.classList.contains("colors")){
    document.body.className = "";
    document.body.classList.add(color);
    localStorage.setItem("name", color);
  }
}
```

```css
.colors {
  display:inline-block;
  width:125px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
  
/* Don't use inline styles (the style property).
   Instead add/remove classes.  */
.elegant { background:#ECF3F9; }
.modern { background:#F1F9EC; }
.classic { background:#F2EBDD; }
.dark { background:#121212; color:#fff; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elegant colors">Elegant</div>
  <div class="modern colors">Modern</div>
  <div class="classic colors">Classic</div>
  <div class="dark colors">Turn off the lights</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made it work with your help. Thank you very much Scott

Comment: Just a question: the text in the dark mode DIV is "Turn off the lights" how can I fix this item?

Comment: @thesubfolders I'll adjust the answer to show this.